# Raw transaction hex from etherscan?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, raw-transaction, pending-transactions, txpool

Anyway to get the raw Hex of a transaction from etherscan?

I know in Bitcoin you can do this on blockchain info with ?format=hex

I want to rebroadcast a tx when it gets dropped from the mempool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etherscan does display the Raw Transaction hash. On the TxInfo page, top right pull down menu there is an option to extract the raw transaction hash (Get Raw Txn)

The output looks something like this https://etherscan.io/getRawTx?tx=0x4b353f2ac768fb3a4d1be17bf2ced520a60beb3a154ce1b145bcb6391bc84a7b

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data directly from a node using something like the Infura public nodes and the RPC. Not sure which RPC interface to use, but here's the documentation for both Infura and the node's RPC. No need to go to EtherScan (although, having said that, they may have an interface--someone else can answer).

Infura: https://infura.io/
Node RPC: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

And, just for good measure, QuickNode: https://quiknode.io/

Comment: So no free website interface? I'm only a noob so I don't know what the hell I'm doing with rpc json

Comment: Etherscan, as you noted, is one such web api. Not sure if there are others. Sorry.